# C++ choose method based argument's dynamic type

Tags: c++, oop

## Question

Imagine I have some simulator library, that takes from me some objects (aka event handlers) and generates events for these objects by calling their `handle_event(Event)` method. The library provides me with the following classes:

```
class Event {}; // Base class for all events
// All event classes are derived from `Event`
class SomeParticularEvent : public Event {}; // Some event class
class AnotherParticularEvent : public Event {}; // Some event class


// Object aka event handler. I should inherit this class and then give objects to the simulator
class AbstractEventHandler
{
public:
        virtual void handle_event(Event) = 0;
};
```

I want to implement an object that handles different events differently. The first code I came up with is the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyObject : public AbstractEventHandler
{
public:
        void actual_handle_event(SomeParticularEvent)
        {
                std::cout << "`SomeParticularEvent` occurred\n";
        }

        void actual_handle_event(AnotherParticularEvent)
        {
                std::cout << "`AnotherParticularEvent` occurred\n";
        }

        void actual_handle_event(Event e)
        {
                std::cerr << "Unknown event type occurred\n";
        }

        virtual void handle_event(Event e) override
        {   
                actual_handle_event(e);
        }   
};
```

Сontrary to my expectations, `MyObject::handle_event(Event)` will always call `MyObject::actual_handle_event(Event)` regardless of the dynamic type of `e`.

My question is: What is the correct way to implement `MyObject` (preferrably, making it possible to easily add new event type)?

---

## All the code together

```
#include <iostream>


class Event {}; // Base class for all events
// All event classes are derived from `Event`
class SomeParticularEvent : public Event {}; // Some event class
class AnotherParticularEvent : public Event {}; // Some event class


class AbstractEventHandler
{
public:
        virtual void handle_event(Event) = 0;
};


class MyObject : public AbstractEventHandler
{
public:
        void actual_handle_event(SomeParticularEvent)
        {
                std::cout << "`SomeParticularEvent` occurred\n";
        }

        void actual_handle_event(AnotherParticularEvent)
        {
                std::cout << "`AnotherParticularEvent` occurred\n";
        }

        void actual_handle_event(Event e)
        {
                std::cerr << "Unknown event type occurred\n";
        }

        virtual void handle_event(Event e) override
        {
                actual_handle_event(e);
        }
};


int main()
{
        MyObject o{};
        o.handle_event(SomeParticularEvent{}); // Prints "Unknown event type occurred"
}
```

---

## Additional question

Is it also possible to create a class derived from `MyObject` and implement **additional** event handlers (not override old ones, but add support for new events) without rewriting the `handle_event` method in the derived class?

Comment: `void handle_event(Event e)` takes the argument by value, performing object slicing. So you will always only have an `Event`, regardless of what the type of the original object was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the requirements in the question and things discussed in the comments to @ypnos answer, I believe that you want or need to implement the visitor pattern here.

One possible implementation would look like this (based on the Wikipedia article about Visitor Pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#C++_example)

```
#include <iostream>

// Forward declare all Event classes
class Event;
class SomeParticularEvent;
class AnotherParticularEvent;

class AbstractEventHandler
{
public:
        virtual void handle_event(const Event&) = 0;
        virtual void handle_event(const SomeParticularEvent&) = 0;
        virtual void handle_event(const AnotherParticularEvent&) = 0;
};

class Event {
public:
    // virtual function for accepting the "visitor"
    virtual void accept(AbstractEventHandler& handler) {
        handler.handle_event(*this);
    }
}; // Base class for all events
// All event classes are derived from `Event`
class SomeParticularEvent : public Event {
public:
    // Needs to be overriden to call `handle_event` with the correct type
    void accept(AbstractEventHandler& handler) override {
        handler.handle_event(*this);
    }
}; // Some event class
class AnotherParticularEvent : public Event {
public:
    void accept(AbstractEventHandler& handler) override {
        handler.handle_event(*this);
    }
}; // Some event class

class MyObject : public AbstractEventHandler
{
public:
        void handle_event(const SomeParticularEvent&) override
        {
                std::cout << "`SomeParticularEvent` occurred\n";
        }

        void handle_event(const AnotherParticularEvent&) override
        {
                std::cout << "`AnotherParticularEvent` occurred\n";
        }

        void handle_event(const Event& e) override
        {
                std::cerr << "Unknown event type occurred\n";
        }
};


int main()
{
        MyObject o{};
        SomeParticularEvent{}.accept(o);
        AnotherParticularEvent{}.accept(o);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is much closer to what I want. The problem is that in the provided code implementation of `MyObject` needs to be modified every time the simulator developers decide to add new event type, but I believe it is easy to overcome: I would add a pure-virtual method `AbstractEventHandler::handle_default_event()` and make all the `handle_event` methods call it by default. In this case, for the derived object I need to only overwrite the default handler and methods for events I actually need to handle (please, tel if you see a better solution)

Comment: What you say is definitely true and an unavoidable issue with the Visitor pattern. Your proposed solution certainly is one way of dealing with it. In some more complex projects you might also have a code generator that handles generating the `AbstractEventHandler` with all its `virtual` functions as well as the individual `Event`s with the overriden `accept` functions, so that you only have to manually write the concrete visitor functions (e.g.: this is the approach used in ANTLR)

Answer (score 0):

In your method `handle_event()` object slicing occurs. You should pass (const) references for the inheritance to work correctly, or pointers.

However, this does not help with your case when dispatching internally from `handle_event()` to `actual_handle_event()`.

A brute-force solution would be to explicitely dispatch by trying `dynamic_casts`. You would need to override `handle_event()` in derived classes to extend it. It also doesn't look that pretty (indicating a design problem).

What is typically done in these situations is that the objects in question (`Event`) would provide an interface for querying the type, e.g. an abstract `type()` getter that is overridden.

Comment: Does not seem like const references work either: https://ideone.com/rOtK85

Comment: @Kolay.Ne I'm guessing that you probably need to implement the visitor pattern?

Comment: @UnholySheep, just read about the pattern on Wikipedia, but don't quite see how to apply it here. As far as I understand, events are things to be visited and event handlers are visitors. But in that case either I need to declare a method per event type in the `Event` class (but they are derived from `Event`. Is it even possible?) or leave it as is, but in that case, again, a common method, accepting general `Event` object, gets called, not a specific one

Comment: I'm sorry that was not a real answer. I edited my answer to reflect what's going on. Not extremely helpful so I might simply delete it later.

Comment: @Kolay.Ne What's your problem with the visitor pattern? That you cannot add the abstract method to `Event`?

Comment: What should `type()` from the answer's suggestion return? Is there a way to exactly return a type in C++ (so that I can then cast an object to it)? Or do you mean it should return e.g. an enum object to be then checked in `handle_event()`?

Comment: @ypnos, I either don't get how I should apply it or don't see how its application helps. If it is suggested to add an abstract method of `Event` for each of the derived events, then it does not seem much better than the brute-force approach

Comment: I guess your question is obsoleted by their excellent answer.